# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, typed, typed.js

I m using this library https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/ .I have added all the script files at the end of body code but still i m getting an error in console. My code is:

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>LUNA-NG</title>

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontAwesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooplate-style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/typed.js/assets/demos.css">
    </head>

 <body>
<span class="typed"></span>
 <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/animejs/anime.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.interactive_3d.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
  $(".typed").typed({
    strings: ["Typed.js is a jQuery plugin that types.", "Enter in any string,", "and watch it type at the speed you've set,", "backspace what it's typed,", "and begin a new sentence for however many strings you've set."],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
});
        </script>
```

Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):259)
    at j (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like that library is not a jQiery plugin. Try using the `Typed` constructor the way the README in the repo you linked shows.

Comment: @Paulpro https://codepen.io/merb/pen/yOwJjj look at this code please.

Comment: @waheedshah It appears to *no longer* be a jQuery plugin, being rewritten without jQuery as of v2. The last update to v1 is [v1.1.7](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/releases/tag/v1.1.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m using the cdn for typed.js library. This is working fine now. I was giving the right path even though i was getting error so i decid to move to cdn. Below is the script i have included.Thanks for your answers

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur due to some of the reasons:
1. The jquery file you have included may have the wrong path.
2. Jquery file may be included on the page more than once.

Please check above points and if don't work then we can discuss it further.

Comment: $ is valid here

Comment: the problem is in including the typed package

Comment: I have checked more thoroughly before posting it. I have included the jquery path right. And it is included just once in file, but still i m facing this.

Comment: console.log(Typed) check this one whether it is return a string or undefined

Comment: i have one' <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.interactive_3d.js"></script>' library that requires javascript and that is working fine but this library is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is just to re-install typed.js from this path.
I have the same problem and I did the same solution and it works for me  now
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js